# Pyplot throws error when program exits

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, out-of-memory, figure

forum.

I recently came across an error stemming from the matplotlib.pyplot module. I am using this in conjunction with wxPython and threading.Thread, and I am using Python version 2.7.

Here's what happens. I import the module just fine, and I'm even able to generate figures and plot them how I want. However, when I try to exit the program, I get a traceback of errors within the pyplot module.

EDIT: See image below.
[image]

Note that this ONLY happens if I instantiate at least one pyplot.figure() object.

This error has not occurred in the past, and I do not know what the source is. Any help in getting rid of this error message on exit would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**For the record, I actually found a solution to the problem. Apparently, it's just a bad idea to generate pyplot figures within a Thread object. Once I moved the methods over to another object, the errors went away. But feel free to try and explain this!**

Comment: Please post an image and tracebacks, thanks

Comment: Image added. Thanks for the reputation help!